# Change the values of a column in a specific condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, na

Here, I made 2 columns `y` and `delta`

```
y=matrix(c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0),nrow=8)
delta=matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),nrow=8)
```

What I want to do now is make new `y`.
I want to treat `delta` as an indicator for missing values of `y`.
If `delta` is 1, I will treat `y` as observed.
If `delta` is 0, I will treat `y` as missing.
So the expected output for `y` should be

```
y=matrix(c(1,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA),nrow=8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use convert the 0 elements in delta to `NA` and multiply by y

```
(NA^!delta) * y
```

-output

```
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]   NA
[3,]   NA
[4,]   NA
[5,]    0
[6,]   NA
[7,]   NA
[8,]   NA
```